# Difference in placeholder text color and select dropdown

Tags: html, css

Hello I would like to ask a question regarding css style.

I put the same color value in the placeholder text and also in a select dropdown. But the color that the browser shows differs.

Anyone can explain why this happens?

Here is an example:
http://scratchpad.io/abounding-coat-5186

edit: What I want to achieve is exactly the same text-color. I dont want that opacity effect that the placeholder has.

Comment: on which browser in my side all working fine

Comment: On Chrome v.48.0 the `color` attribute is not applied to the placeholder text, whereas the text of the option entry is valid colored text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite placeholder styles with this pseudo-classes/pseudo-elements

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari/ */
   color: red;
   opacity: 1;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
   opacity: 1;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
   opacity: 1;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {  /* IE */
   color: red;  
   opacity: 1;
}
```

JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vwbr178k/1/)

Comment: Sorry maybe my question was not on spot. What I see on your example is not the same text color. I want it to be exactly the same. And the opacity as well.

Comment: Yes that was it. It was something simple really. -_- Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change placeholder. here how to change placeholder color

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
```

[Read More](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)